# Detecting whenever a user types - in the Gutenberg editor, and checking if there is a preceding or succeeding - then converting both to an em dash

Tags: block-editor, events, react

I'm having quite a lot of trouble trying to hook an event listener to WordPress's Gutenberg Editor. There is very little documentation on this, and ChatGPT doesn't give very good answers too. What I want to do is to detect whenever a user makes changes to the post content, then scanning the content to convert all `--` into `—` (an em dash).

Ideally, it only fires when a user types a -, and it checks forward and backward to see if there is another -, and if there is, it replaces both. Here is what I have at the moment, and it just scans the entire post to replace all `--` with `—`, and *even* this is not working.

```
(function(wp) {
    // Wait for the editor to initialize
    wp.domReady(function() {
    
        wp.data.subscribe(function() {
        
            var editor = wp.data.select('core/editor');
            var core = wp.data.select('core');
        
            if (editor && core.getPostType(editor.getEditedPostAttribute('type'))) {
                var postContent = editor.getEditedPostContent();
                var modifiedContent = postContent.replace(/(?<=\s)--(?=\s)/g, '—');
                wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({ content: modifiedContent });
            }
        });
    });
})(window.wp);
```

The problem is that `subscribe()` fires whenever the post content is changed, and `editPost()` changes the content, which causes an infinite recursion and a Maximum Call Stack Exceeded error (i.e. stack overflow).

Even when I try to add a flag to check this, the same stack overflow error happens:

```
(function(wp) {
    // Wait for the editor to initialize
    wp.domReady(function() {

        var ignoreSubscribe = false;

        wp.data.subscribe(function() {
            // If this is true, ignore this subscribe call.
            if(ignoreSubscribe) {
                ignoreSubscribe = false;
                return;
            }
        
            var editor = wp.data.select('core/editor');
            var core = wp.data.select('core');
        
            if (editor && core.getPostType(editor.getEditedPostAttribute('type'))) {
                var postContent = editor.getEditedPostContent();
                var modifiedContent = postContent.replace(/(?<=\s)--(?=\s)/g, '—');
                wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({ content: modifiedContent });

                ignoreSubscribe = true;
            }
        });
    });
})(window.wp);
```

I don't know what is wrong here, so some help will be greatly appreciated. **Also, if you can help me figure out how to only detect the event when a user types a `-` and only scan *that* character, that will be even better.**

Preferrably, I would like to do this without having to set up React too, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to this. Instead of adding an event listener to the editor, I hooked some additional functionality onto Gutenberg's Autocompleter instead:

[image: Gutenberg autocompleter]

I wrote a post here detailing how I did this, if anyone is looking to do the same thing: https://blog.terresquall.com/2023/06/how-i-made-double-dashes-automatically-convert-to-em-dashes-in-wordpress-gutenberg-editor/